# How do I call a discord.py function multiple times for each item in a list?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Im using discord API in python to manage a Discord bot. This command creates a list of people in a certain discord channel.

I have a function:

```py
async def attendance(ctx, channel):
    # code here that creates a variable with member names
    await bot.say(printdiscordnames)
```

I want to call the above function each time with a different channel name in a list

So I would do:

```py
async def attendanceall(ctx):
    channel_list = ['voice1', 'voice2', 'voice3']
    for item in channel_list:
        attendance(item)
```

Basically I want to do !attendanceall in discord and it will do the first function which makes a list and prints it in discord for each channel in the list.

My issue is I dont know how to call the first function for each channel name in the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
async def attendanceall(ctx):
channel_list = ['voice1', 'voice2', 'voice3']
for item in channel_list:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(attendance(item))
```

you can do this to run an asynchronous function or use the one below as another way of running it

```
async def attendanceall(ctx):
channel_list = ['voice1', 'voice2', 'voice3']
for item in channel_list:
    client.loop.create_task(attendance(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
async def attendanceall(ctx):
    channel_list = ['voice1', 'voice2', 'voice3']
    for item in channel_list:
        await attendance(item)
```

refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) link for help